# Looking to use javascript for multiple select menus when user clicks submit

Tags: javascript, select, onclick

I am essentially trying to copy this product filter (LINK-->) www.safavieh.com/rugs (<--LINK) except instead of 6 select menus I am using 4.

Should I use the Onclick event? I  am pretty darn new to JS, I have done some form validation in PHP but our e-commerce platform doesn't support PHP so I need to use JS.

I'm obviously not asking for someone to write it out but rather lead the way and point me towards the right direction. It's important that I learn this myself.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: First, what are you clicking? The submit button or the select boxes.  Second, what do you ant to do onclick?  Validate? Submit the form?

Comment: You would click the submit button. When the user clicks I need to bring the user to the filtered page. So if they chose lets say "AGRA Rugs" and then chose "Blue/Aqua/Navy" they would be brought to agra rugs that are blue. They need to be able so select an option from whichever 4 of the menus they chose and click select after and have the JS do the sorting and bring them to the correct page.

Comment: Are you filtering server side or client side?  In other words, do you need to send the values of the select menus to the server, or not?

Comment: No it would be client side, the categories already exist on our website the select menus would just be arranging them to the users needs. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the select menus in a form element, and use an `<input type=submit>` for the submit button, then you can use the form's `onSubmit` event to do any preprocessing before form submission.  All of the form's fields can be accessed through the forms domNode.  For example if you access form `<form id='myForm'>` with `var form = document.getElementById('myForm');`, then select `<select id="mySelect>`'s value can be gotten with `form.myForm.value`.

Since your filtering client side, you can still use the onSubmit event, just prevent it's default action:

```
form.onSubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // filtering code goes here.
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, jumpnett. I will add reputation right away. Last question is do you think I will face any browser compatibility issues with something like this?

Comment: That's standard JS, so I don't think there would be any issues, but it is best to test all browsers you'll be using to be on the safe side.

Comment: For more form specifics, MDN is a great resource:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/form
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Accessibility/ARIA/forms/Basic_form_hints

Comment: Very cool, i'll be sure to check everything out once I leave work.